# Balanced Directed Graph Realization

Tags: algorithms, graphs, randomized-algorithms, directed-graphs

I have a list of integers: each integer represents a node in a directed graph, and the value of the integer is both the desired indegree and outdegree of said node.

Some research suggests that this is called a "balanced graph", and that my list of integers represents a "realization problem."

I'm looking for a relatively efficient algorithm to generate such a graph.  In cases where it is not possible, I'd like to reduce the highest integers in the list until a solution exists.

It would also be ideal if I can use different random seeds to generate different graphs for the same input until I can find one I like (so... I guess one that has some randomness to it?)

Does such an algorithm already exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an instance of the [directed graph realization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_realization_problem).  The problem can be solved in polynomial time; see Wikipedia for links to algorithms.